# Change editor look in eclipse indigo for xml-files only

Tags: xml, eclipse, editor

I'm searching a solution to change the editor look in eclipse, but only for xml-files. So for example, when I create an Android project, the java-files should appear as usual, but the xml-files let's say with a black background and white font. Is there an easy way to achieve this? I found tons of "tutorials" in the web, but nothing seems to be exactly what I want.

I got Eclipse 3.7.2

Comment: You can use eclipse color themes . But it will change all editors .
http://eclipsecolorthemes.org/

Comment: Easiest way would be to add an XML editor using an Eclipse plug-in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently installed the Aptana Studio 3 plugin in eclipse, and there is a theme creator and selector, which not only changes the editor look of web-related filetypes. It is possible to change whole eclipse's look too.

Once installed the Aptana plugin, you can find this option via

`"Window" -> "Preferences" -> "Aptana Studio" -> Themes`